# Ant and Eclipse build

Tags: java, ant

I  build my project from Eclipse and with ant(javac) and class files has different size. why is this might occur?

Program in Eclipse work correctly, but program in ant don`t work

Comment: what do you mean different size?

Comment: files, generated in eclipse has bigger size, than files generated with ant(javac)

Answer (score 2):

They are different sizes because Eclipse includes its own Java compiler; it does *not* use `javac`. Although there isn't an enormous amount of room for creativity in how Java is compiled to bytecode, there's a *little* room for interpretation, so it's not surprising that different compilers would produce different class files.

Answer (score 2):

*Ernest Friedman-Hill*'s answer is correct.

But another possible cause is that you have different settings in Ant and Eclipse. e.g. Eclipse is probably generating debugging information (line numbers etc) in the class files and Ant is not.